# What is equivalent annotation in WebSphere Liberty for Jboss EJb3 annotation @SecurityDomain("") and WebSphere annotation @Webcontext

Tags: java, jboss, websphere-liberty

I have Migrating Jboss application to WebSphere Liberty. I must remove all Jboss reference library. While doing that am facing issue in some annotation. Jboss application using `@SecurityDomain("Authentication")` and `@Webcontext` What is equivalent annotation in WebSphere Liberty for these two annotation.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? There are no such annotations in Liberty, but instead you should use web.xml to define login config and security constraints, and in server.xml configure user registry.

Comment: What you told that is the one I want to achieve, I need to Migrate Jboss application to Liberty. I accept your answer. Can you please let me know some samples or website to configure web.xml and server.xml in Liberty for login and security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requirements (there are some defaults if omitted) , you would want to have the following in `web.xml`:

1) Security constraints which describes resources of your app with mapping to roles e.g.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>testing</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

2) Security role definitions (athough they can be done also via annotation `@DeclareRoles`)

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>testing</role-name>
 </security-role>
```

3) Login config , used when want to have form login (if omitted then defaults to Basic):

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
 </login-config>
```

Then configure user registry in Liberty. You can have file based, LDAP, or custom if needed. `server.xml` config depends on the type of registry used. Finally you need to bind users to security roles. It is too broad to include all options here, so just adding relevant links. (create separate questions for more detailed issues, if needed).

Useful links:

- [Very basic security configuration](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_sec_quickstart.html)
- [Start page for Configuring a user registry in Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_sec_registries.html)
- [Registry users to security role bindings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_authorization.html)
- [Configuring a custom form login page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_config_custom_user_login_form.html)